# Reoder featured articles after migration to joomla 4

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla4

I have upgrade my site from Joomla 3.10.x to Joomla 4.3.2.

My homepage shows a list of featured articles. I have create new featured articles and if i change the order in the backend with drag & drop, after refresh the order of the list remain the same, both in backend and frontend.

Any ideas on why the new articles dont exist in the _content_frontpage table so i can change the order of the featured articles?

I have check the tables _content and _content_frontpage in the db and i cant find the new article ids in the column content_id. If i change with drag & drop the order of an article with an id that exist in the content_id column, then the order is changing successfully.